# Cannot pipe to Get-Content from binary module using FileInfo

Tags: powershell

I am having a hard time piping a file to `Get-Content` (version PS 5.1).

Module code:

```
[Cmdlet(VerbsDiagnostic.Test, "FilePiping")]
public class PSTestFilePiping : PSCmdlet
{
    [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory = true)]
    public string FileName { get; set; }

    protected override void ProcessRecord()
    {
        WriteObject(new System.IO.FileInfo(FileName));
    }
}
```

Commands:

`$x = Test-FilePiping .\readme.txt`

`$y = gci .\readme.txt`

(I am using a relative path for simplicity)

Both `$x` and `$y` are a `FileInfo` object according to `GetType()`:

```
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
True     True     FileInfo                                 System.IO.FileSystemInfo
```

Yet I cannot do:

`$x | gc`

`The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.`

but I can do:

`$y | gc`

This has me flummoxed.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: So I might be completely wrong here but the input object `$x` should have a property with name `Path`, `LiteralPath` or `PSPath` (accepted as `ValueFromPipeline` by `Get-Content`) and said properties should contain the `Full Path` of the file. If both conditions are met then `Get-Content` should accept your object and read it without problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to [@santiago-squarzon's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67351935/9164015), there are two things worth noting here:

- PowerShell commands like `Get-Item` and `Get-ChildItem` are not just made for the FileSystem so return information for the relevant provider, which is where values like PSPath come from.
- Targeting a relative path with `new FileInfo()` will probably not find the file you are expecting, so we should get the full path just in case.

This can be achieved in your cmdlet so that it returns the `PSPath` property necessary for `Get-Content`.

Sample:

```sh
dotnet new classlib -o PSSample -n PSSample
cd PSSample
dotnet add package PowerShellStandard.Library --version 5.1.0
code . # I am using VSC - open your editor in the directory.
# Set target framework to netstandard2.0 in .csproj
# Copy and paste below in to Class1.cs
dotnet restore
dotnet build
ipmo .\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\PSSample.dll
Test-FilePiping -FileName .\Class1.cs | FL *
Test-FilePiping -FileName .\Class1.cs | Get-Content
```

Cmdlet class:

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Management.Automation;

namespace PSSample
{
    [Cmdlet(VerbsDiagnostic.Test, "FilePiping")]
    public class PSTestFilePiping : PSCmdlet
    {
        [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory = true)]
        public string FileName { get; set; }

        protected override void ProcessRecord()
        {
            string filePath = GetRelativePath(FileName);
            var item = InvokeProvider.Item.Get(filePath);
            WriteObject(item, true);    // true enumerates the collection, because InvokeProvider.Item.Get() returns a collection.
        }

        protected string GetRelativePath(string path)
        {
            string currentDir = GetVariableValue("PWD").ToString();

            if (Path.IsPathRooted(path) == true || path.StartsWith("\\", StringComparison.CurrentCulture))
            {
                // Nothing to see here.
            }
            else
            {
                if (path == ".")
                {
                    path = currentDir;
                }
                else if (path.StartsWith("..", StringComparison.CurrentCulture))
                {
                    path = Path.Combine(
                        string.Join("\\",
                            currentDir.Split('\\').Take(currentDir.Split('\\').Count() - path.Split('\\').Count(p => p == "..")).ToArray()
                        ),
                        string.Join("\\", path.Split('\\').Where(f => f != "..").ToArray()));
                }
                else if (path.StartsWith(".", StringComparison.CurrentCulture))
                {
                    path = Path.Combine(currentDir, path.Substring(2));
                }
                else
                {
                    path = Path.Combine(currentDir, path);
                }
            }

            return path;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
PS C:\Code\PSSample> Test-FilePiping -FileName .\Class1.cs | FL *


PSPath            : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Code\PSSample\Class1.cs
PSParentPath      : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Code\PSSample
PSChildName       : Class1.cs
PSDrive           : C
PSProvider        : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem
PSIsContainer     : False
Mode              : -a----
VersionInfo       : File:             C:\Code\PSSample\Class1.cs
                    InternalName:
                    OriginalFilename:
                    FileVersion:
                    FileDescription:
                    Product:
                    ProductVersion:
                    Debug:            False
                    Patched:          False
                    PreRelease:       False
                    PrivateBuild:     False
                    SpecialBuild:     False
                    Language:

BaseName          : Class1
Target            : {}
LinkType          :
Name              : Class1.cs
Length            : 1947
DirectoryName     : C:\Code\PSSample
Directory         : C:\Code\PSSample
IsReadOnly        : False
Exists            : True
FullName          : C:\Code\PSSample\Class1.cs
Extension         : .cs
CreationTime      : 02/05/2021 13:03:22
CreationTimeUtc   : 02/05/2021 12:03:22
LastAccessTime    : 02/05/2021 13:04:13
LastAccessTimeUtc : 02/05/2021 12:04:13
LastWriteTime     : 02/05/2021 13:04:00
LastWriteTimeUtc  : 02/05/2021 12:04:00
Attributes        : Archive



PS C:\Code\PSSample> Test-FilePiping -FileName .\Class1.cs | Get-Content
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Management.Automation;

namespace PSSample
{
    [Cmdlet(VerbsDiagnostic.Test, "FilePiping")]
    public class PSTestFilePiping : PSCmdlet
    {
        [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory = true)]
        public string FileName { get; set; }

        protected override void ProcessRecord()
        {
            string filePath = GetRelativePath(FileName);
            var item = InvokeProvider.Item.Get(filePath);
            WriteObject(item, true);    // true enumerates the collection, because InvokeProvider.Item.Get() returns a collection.
        }

        protected string GetRelativePath(string path)
        {
            string currentDir = GetVariableValue("PWD").ToString();

            if (Path.IsPathRooted(path) == true || path.StartsWith("\\", StringComparison.CurrentCulture))
            {
                // Nothing to see here.
            }
            else
            {
                if (path == ".")
                {
                    path = currentDir;
                }
                else if (path.StartsWith("..", StringComparison.CurrentCulture))
                {
                    path = Path.Combine(
                        string.Join("\\",
                            currentDir.Split('\\').Take(currentDir.Split('\\').Count() - path.Split('\\').Count(p => p == "..")).ToArray()
                        ),
                        string.Join("\\", path.Split('\\').Where(f => f != "..").ToArray()));
                }
                else if (path.StartsWith(".", StringComparison.CurrentCulture))
                {
                    path = Path.Combine(currentDir, path.Substring(2));
                }
                else
                {
                    path = Path.Combine(currentDir, path);
                }
            }

            return path;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this elaborate and helpful answer; I used a relative path just to make my question as simple as possible. I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: What does this line do: `var item = InvokeProvider.Item.Get(filePath);`?

Comment: Inheriting from [PSCmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.pscmdlet.invokeprovider?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0) gives you access to the [various providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_providers?view=powershell-7.1) in PowerShell. This allows you to [access Items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.providerintrinsics?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0) in the FileSystem, Registry, Certificates, etc.

Comment: Okay, that is fascinating. If I understand correctly, `InvokeProvider.Item.Get(filePath)` is like invoking a new .Net `FileInfo` object, but on PS steroids, right? So, if my only intent was to make the ouput pipeable to `Get-Content`, I could just as well emit a anonymous object with a `Get-Content` consumable parameter, right?

Comment: You could put it that way, @mklement0 explained a little more about the Extended Type System in PowerShell. It is getting a single item (not necessarily a file) via the provider methods.`Get-Content` will accept a `PSPath` property as per my example above by PropertyName. If you can create the path as is and a property with the name `PSPath`. It may be better to do it with the [`Path`](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Management/commands/management/ContentCommandBase.cs#L25-L27) property based off `FullName` in `System.IO.FileInfo`.

Comment: Here is an old blog about [how binding by property name works.](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/learn-about-using-powershell-value-binding-by-property-name/)

Answer (score 3):

Hopefully this helps you identify your error:

```
PS /> 'Hello world!' > test.txt
PS /> $reader = [System.IO.FileInfo]::new('test.txt')
```

If I try to pipe this object directly to `Get-Content` it will throw with the same error you're getting:

**Using this:**

```
PS /> $reader | Get-Content
```

**Or this:**

```
PS /> $reader.FullName | Get-Content
```

**Results in:**

```
Get-Content: The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.
```

This is because none of the properties returned by `[System.IO.FileInfo]` matches those paremeters accepted as `ValueFromPipelineByProperyName` by `Get-Content`:

```
PS /> $reader | gm -MemberType Property

   TypeName: System.IO.FileInfo

Name              MemberType Definition
----              ---------- ----------
Attributes        Property   System.IO.FileAttributes Attributes {get;set;}
CreationTime      Property   datetime CreationTime {get;set;}
CreationTimeUtc   Property   datetime CreationTimeUtc {get;set;}
Directory         Property   System.IO.DirectoryInfo Directory {get;}
DirectoryName     Property   string DirectoryName {get;}
Exists            Property   bool Exists {get;}
Extension         Property   string Extension {get;}
FullName          Property   string FullName {get;}
IsReadOnly        Property   bool IsReadOnly {get;set;}
LastAccessTime    Property   datetime LastAccessTime {get;set;}
LastAccessTimeUtc Property   datetime LastAccessTimeUtc {get;set;}
LastWriteTime     Property   datetime LastWriteTime {get;set;}
LastWriteTimeUtc  Property   datetime LastWriteTimeUtc {get;set;}
Length            Property   long Length {get;}
Name              Property   string Name {get;}
```

However if we create an object with any of the properties I mentioned in my comment, `Get-Content` will accept it as input and read it without any problems:

```
PS /> [PSCustomObject]@{ Path = $reader.FullName } | Get-Content
Hello world!

PS /> [PSCustomObject]@{ LiteralPath = $reader.FullName } | Get-Content
Hello world!

PS /> [PSCustomObject]@{ PSPath = $reader.FullName } | Get-Content
Hello world!
```

**`Get-ChildItem` works fine because the object returned has the PSPath property.**

The best way to identify which parameters are accepted as `ValueFromPipelineByProperyName` is to rely on [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-7.1):

| -LiteralPath |  |
| --- | --- |
| Type | String[] |
| Aliases | PSPath, LP |
| Position | Named |
| Default value | None |
| **Accept pipeline input** | **True** |
| Accept wildcard characters | False |

Comment: I unvoted (that is not even a word!) this as an answer because while it explains the issue and is helpful, an even more complete answer was submitted.

Answer (score 3):

To *complement* the existing, helpful answers with some **background information**:

It is the PowerShell `FileSystem` [provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Providers) that decorates the `System.IO.FileSystemInfo` instances (both [`System.IO.FileInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.FileInfo) and [`System.IO.DirectoryInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.DirectoryInfo)) that [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) and [`Get-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-item) emit with additional properties such as `PSPath` (among several others <sup>[1]</sup>), using PowerShell's [ETS (Extended Type System)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Types.ps1xml).

The `.PSPath` property values of pipeline input objects are what bind to the `-LiteralPath` parameter of cmdlets such as [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content), due to said parameter being declared with the `ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName` property *and* `LiteralPath` being decorated with an `[Alias("PSPath")]` attribute; that is, `PSPath` is an *alias* (another name for) `LiteralPath`.

As of this writing, the PowerShell providers add these ETS properties as *instance* properties, which is the reason that a *directly constructed* `System.IO.FileInfo` does *not* have these properties, resulting in the symptom you saw (the absence of the `.PSPath` property prevented binding to the `-LiteralPath` parameter).

*If* the providers were to use *type-level* ETS properties (associated with the .NET type itself rather than with specific instances of it), this problem would go away, as such properties would then surface irrespective of how an instance was constructed.

See [GitHub issue #4347](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4347) for a discussion.

---

<sup>[1] The full list of added properties is: `PSPath`, `PSParentPath`, `PSChildName`, `PSDrive`, `PSProvider`, `PSIsContainer`,
`Mode`, `BaseName`, `Target`, `LinkType`.</sup>

Comment: I was almost sure it was `ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName` instead of `ValueFromPipeline` just needed an expert to confirm it. Thank you sir! If it was `ValueFromPipeline` then `$reader.FullName | Get-Content` from my example probably should've worked right?

Comment: My pleasure, @SantiagoSquarzon. Yes, with `ValueFromPipeline` `$reader.FullName | Get-Content` would work, given that `LiteralPath` is `[string[]]`-typed and any object can be converted to string.